# NFL data scraper

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, pandas, beautifulsoup

I made a Python 3 class that scrapes data from [Pro Football Reference](https://www.pro-football-reference.com/). It uses `requests` and `beautifulsoup4` to gather the data and places it into a `pandas` data frame. All you need to do is create an object and use the `get_data()` method to get the data frame. This method needs a `start_year`, `end_year`, and `table_type` as arguments. Valid table types can be found in the class' docstring.

A usage demonstration can be found at the bottom of the code. It scrapes [2017 Passing Data](https://www.pro-football-reference.com/years/2017/passing.htm) and [2018 Passing Data](https://www.pro-football-reference.com/years/2018/passing.htm). You can also view the code [on GitHub](https://github.com/keving90/NFL-Data-Python/blob/2547cedf36b46fb5ec901a27dbb7eea6ee25708c/pro_football_ref/pro_ref2.py).

```
"""
This module contains a FootballRefScraper class used to scrape NFL data from www.pro-football-reference.com. It places
the data into a Pandas data frame, which can be saved as a CSV file. Built using Python 3.7.0.
"""

import requests
import bs4
import pandas as pd


class FootballRefScraper(object):
    """
    Scrapes NFL data from www.pro-football-reference.com and places it into a Pandas data frame. Multiple years of data
    can be scraped and placed into a single data frame for the same statistical category. Each category is referred to 
    as a 'table type'. Possible table types include:

    'rushing': Rushing data.
    'passing': Passing data.
    'receiving': Receiving data.
    'kicking': Field goal, point after touchdown, and punt data.
    'returns': Punt and kick return data.
    'scoring': All types of scoring data, such as touchdowns (defense/offense), two point conversions, kicking, etc.
    'fantasy': Rushing, receiving, and passing stats, along with fantasy point totals from various leagues.
    'defense': Defensive player stats.

    Each player on Pro Football Reference has their own unique URL. This URL, combined with the year for the player's
    specific season of data, is used as a unique identifier for each row in the data frame. It is used as the data
    frame's index.
    """
    def __init__(self):
        self._tables = ['rushing', 'passing', 'receiving', 'kicking', 'returns', 'scoring', 'fantasy', 'defense']
        self._kicking_cols_to_rename = {
            'fga1': 'att_0-19',
            'fgm1': 'made_0-19',
            'fga2': 'att_20-29',
            'fgm2': 'made_20-29',
            'fga3': 'att_30-39',
            'fgm3': 'made_30-39',
            'fga4': 'att_40-49',
            'fgm4': 'made_40-49',
            'fga5': 'att_50_plus',
            'fgm5': 'made_50_plus'
        }

    @property
    def tables(self):
        """getter: Returns a list of the possible table types to scrape from."""
        return self._tables

    def get_data(self, start_year, end_year, table_type, remove_pro_bowl=True, remove_all_pro=True):
        """
        Gets a data frame of NFL player stats from Pro Football Reference for one for more seasons.
        :param start_year: First season to scrape data from (string or int)
        :param end_year: Final season (inclusive) to scrape data from (string or int)
        :param table_type: Stat category to scrape
        :param remove_pro_bowl: Boolean - If true, removes Pro Bowl accolade ('*') from player's name
        :param remove_all_pro: Boolean - If true, removes All-Pro accolade ('+') from player's name
        :return: Data frame of one or more seasons of data for a given stat category.
        """
        self._check_table_type(table_type)
        start_year, end_year = self._check_start_and_end_years(start_year, end_year)

        if start_year == end_year:
            df = self._get_single_season(start_year, table_type)
        else:
            df = self._get_multiple_seasons(start_year, end_year, table_type)

        # Unique identifier for each player's season of data.
        df.set_index('player_url', inplace=True)

        # Change data from string to numeric, where applicable.
        df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='ignore')

        if remove_pro_bowl or remove_all_pro:
            self._remove_player_accolades(df, remove_pro_bowl, remove_all_pro)

        if table_type.lower() == 'kicking':
            # For kicking data, rename some columns so field goal distance is obvious.
            df = df.rename(index=str, columns=self._kicking_cols_to_rename)

        return df

    def _get_multiple_seasons(self, start_year, end_year, table_type):
        """
        Scrapes multiple seasons of data from Pro Football Reference and puts it into a Pandas data frame.
        :param start_year: First season to scrape data from (string or int)
        :param end_year: Final season (inclusive) to scrape data from (string or int)
        :param table_type: Stat category to scrape
        :return: Data frame with multiple seasons of data for a given stat category.
        """
        # Get seasons to iterate through.
        year_range = self._get_year_range(start_year, end_year)

        # Get a data frame of each season.
        seasons = [self._get_single_season(year, table_type) for year in year_range]

        # Combine all seasons into one large df.
        # sort = False prevents FutureWarning when concatenating data frames with different number of columns (1/18/19)
        big_df = pd.concat(seasons, sort=False)

        return big_df

    def _get_year_range(self, start_year, end_year):
        """
        Uses start_year and end_year to build an iterable sequence.
        :param start_year: Year to begin iterable at.
        :param end_year: Final year in iterable.
        :return: An iterable sequence.
        """
        # Build range iterator depending on how start_year and end_year are related.
        if start_year > end_year:
            year_range = range(start_year, end_year - 1, -1)
        else:
            year_range = range(start_year, end_year + 1)

        return year_range

    def _check_start_and_end_years(self, start_year, end_year):
        """
        Tries to convert start_year and end_year to int, if necessary. Raises ValueError for unsuccessful conversions.
        :param start_year: Data to convert to int
        :param end_year: Data to convert to int
        :return: Tuple - (start_year, end_year)
        """
        # Convert years to int, if needed.
        if not isinstance(start_year, int):
            try:
                start_year = int(start_year)
            except ValueError:
                raise ValueError('Cannot convert start_year to type int.')
        if not isinstance(end_year, int):
            try:
                end_year = int(end_year)
            except ValueError:
                raise ValueError('Cannot convert end_year to type int.')

        return start_year, end_year

    def _get_single_season(self, year, table_type):
        """
        Scrapes a single table from Pro Football Reference and puts it into a Pandas data frame.
        :param year: Season's year.
        :param table_type: String representing the type of table to be scraped.
        :return: A data frame of the scraped table for a single season.
        """
        table = self._get_table(year, table_type)
        header_row = self._get_table_headers(table)
        df_cols = self._get_df_columns(header_row)
        player_elements = self._get_player_rows(table)

        if not player_elements:
            # Table found, but it doesn't have data.
            raise RuntimeError(table_type.capitalize() + " stats table found for year " + str(year)
                               + ", but it does not contain data.")

        season_data = self._get_player_stats(player_elements)

        # Final data frame for single season
        return self._make_df(year, season_data, df_cols)

    def _get_table(self, year, table_type):
        """
        Sends a GET request to Pro-Football Reference and uses BeautifulSoup to find the HTML table.
        :param year: Season's year.
        :param table_type: String representing the type of table to be scraped.
        :return: BeautifulSoup table element.
        """
        # Send a GET request to Pro-Football Reference
        url = 'https://www.pro-football-reference.com/years/' + str(year) + '/' + table_type + '.htm'
        response = requests.get(url)
        response.raise_for_status()

        # Create a BeautifulSoup object.
        soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')

        table = soup.find('table', id=table_type)

        if table is None:
            # No table found
            raise RuntimeError(table_type.capitalize() + " stats table not found for year " + str(year) + ".")

        # Return the table containing the data.
        return table

    def _get_table_headers(self, table_element):
        """
        Extracts the top row of a BeautifulSoup table element.
        :param table_element: BeautifulSoup table element.
        :return: List of header cells from a table.
        """
        # 'thead' contains the table's header row
        head = table_element.find('thead')

        # 'tr' refers to a table row
        col_names = head.find_all('tr')[-1]

        # 'th' is a table header cell
        return col_names.find_all('th')

    def _get_df_columns(self, header_elements):
        """
        Extracts stat names from column header cells.
        :param header_elements: List of header cells
        :return: List of stat names.
        """
        cols_for_single_season = [header_cell['data-stat'] for header_cell in header_elements[1:]]
        cols_for_single_season.insert(1, 'player_url')

        return cols_for_single_season

    def _get_player_rows(self, table_element):
        """
        Gets a list of rows from an HTML table.
        :param table_element: HTML table.
        :return: A list of table row elements.
        """
        # 'tbody' is the table's body
        body = table_element.find('tbody')

        # 'tr' refers to a table row
        return body.find_all('tr')

    def _get_player_stats(self, player_row_elements):
        """
        Gets stats for each player in a table for a season.
        :param player_row_elements: List of table rows where each row is a player's season stat line.
        :return: List where each element is a list containing a player's data for the season.
        """
        season_stats = []
        for player in player_row_elements:
            # 'td' is an HTML table cell
            player_stats = player.find_all('td')

            # Some rows do not contain player data.
            if player_stats:
                clean_stats = self._get_clean_stats(player_stats)
                season_stats.append(clean_stats)

        return season_stats

    def _get_clean_stats(self, stat_row):
        """
        Gets clean text stats for a player's season.
        :param stat_row: List of table cells representing a player's stat line for a season.
        :return: List of strings representing a player's season stat line.
        """
        clean_player_stats = []
        for stat_cell in stat_row:
            clean_player_stats.append(stat_cell.text)

            # Also grab the player's URL so they have a unique identifier when combined with the season's year.
            if stat_cell['data-stat'] == 'player':
                url = self._get_player_url(stat_cell)
                clean_player_stats.append(url)

        return clean_player_stats

    def _get_player_url(self, player_cell):
        """
        Get's a player's unique URL.
        :param player_cell: HTML table cell.
        :return: String - player's unique URL.
        """
        # 'href' is the URL of the page the link goes to.
        href = player_cell.find_all('a', href=True)

        # Return URL string
        return href[0]['href']

    def _make_df(self, year, league_stats, column_names):
        """
        :param year: Season's year.
        :param league_stats: List where each element is a list of stats for a single player.
        :param column_names: List used for data frame's column names.
        :return: A data frame.
        """
        df = pd.DataFrame(data=league_stats, columns=column_names)
        df.insert(loc=3, column='year', value=year)  # Column for current year.

        # Combined player_url + year acts as a unique identifier for a player's season of data.
        df['player_url'] = df['player_url'].apply(lambda x: x + str(year))

        return df

    def _remove_player_accolades(self, df, remove_pro_bowl, remove_all_pro):
        """
        Removes Pro Bowl ('*') and All-Pro ('+') accolades from a player's name.
        :param remove_pro_bowl: Boolean; remove if True
        :param remove_all_pro: Boolean; remove if True
        :return: No return value
        """
        if remove_pro_bowl and not remove_all_pro:
            # Remove '*' in player's name.
            df['player'] = df['player'].apply(lambda x: ''.join(x.split('*')) if '*' in x else x)
        elif not remove_pro_bowl and remove_all_pro:
            # Remove '+' in player's name.
            df['player'] = df['player'].apply(lambda x: ''.join(x.split('+')) if '+' in x else x)
        elif remove_pro_bowl and remove_all_pro:
            # Remove '*', '+', or '*+'.
            df['player'] = df['player'].apply(self._remove_chars)

    def _remove_chars(self, string):
        """
        Removes any combination of a single '*' and '+' from the end of a string.
        :param string: String
        :return: String
        """
        if string.endswith('*+'):
            string = string[:-2]
        elif string.endswith('*') or string.endswith('+'):
            string = string[:-1]

        return string

    def _check_table_type(self, table_type):
        """
        Checks for valid table types. Raises value error for invalid table.
        :param table_type: String
        :return: No return value
        """
        # Only scrapes from tables in self._tables.
        if table_type.lower() not in self._tables:
            raise ValueError("Error, make sure to specify table_type. "
                           + "Can only currently handle the following table names: "
                           + str(self._tables))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    football_ref = FootballRefScraper()
    df = football_ref.get_data(start_year=2017, end_year=2018, table_type='passing')
    df.to_csv('sample_data.csv')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to work on your names. Looking at your github repo, this file is pro_ref2.py? The class name is FootballRefScraper. The site chosen is pro-football-reference.com? What is going on here?

   I don't know why this class exists. The class name should make it obvious. Does this thing exist to be a scraper? Or does it exist to be a data source? IMO, it does not exist to be a scraper, because that would imply it was one of many scrapers and so it would probably be a subclass of some `AbstractScraper` base class. So I think it's a data source, but then why is it called `...Scraper`? Also, what kind of data source is it? Apparently `FootballRef`, but again what's that?

   Assuming this is really intended to be a data source, give the class a better name. `FootballStatistics` or `NflStatistics` make more sense. Alternatively, you might name it after the website, in which case calling it `ProFootballReference` would seem logical.

   If this file contains only the one class, then I suggest you rename the file to `pfr.py` or `profootballreference.py` or some such, and then maybe name the class something like `Gateway` or `API`. Finally, don't call it `get_tables`. Call it `get_stats` since thats what you provide. (You're returning a DataFrame, but you wouldn't call it `get_df` unless there was some alternate flavor to get...)

   ```
   import pfr                       | import pfr
   gateway = pfr.Gateway()          | api = pfr.API()
   df = gateway.get_stats(...)      | df = api.get_stats(...)
   ```
2. As a corollary to #1, consider adding explicit methods for each of the table access calls. Instead of calling `df = gateway.get_stats(..., table_type='passing')` it would be easier and clearer to simply say `df = gateway.get_passing_stats(...)`. Not to mention that a missing method name is easier to debug than a call with a misspelled text string (and your editor might auto-suggest/auto-correct the method!).
3. Don't store the table types and kicking table rename data in the instances. That is class data:

   ```
   class No:
       def __init__(self):
           self.foo = 'foo' # No

   class Yes:
       foo = 'foo' # Yes

       def __init__(self):
           pass
   ```
4. The `.tables` property should be `.table_types` or `.stats_types`
5. The `get_data` (a.k.a. `get_stats`) function has an awkward interface. Instead of trying to jam everything into `start_year` and `end_year`, try allowing multiple named parameters and requiring them to be exclusive. Also, be willing to accept multiple parameter types:

   ```
   # Cannot use year=, years= in same call
   df = api.get_passing_stats(year=2017)  
   df = api.get_passing_stats(years=(2013, 2017)) # Two explicit years
   df = api.get_passing_stats(years=range(2011, 2019, 2)) # Only odd year data?

   # Cannot use tables= in get_XXX_stats call.
   # Cannot use table= and tables= in same call
   df = api.get_stats(year=2018, table='kicking')
   df = api.get_stats(years=(2017, 2018), tables=('passing', 'running', 'scoring'))
   ```

   6. Don't be afraid of a DataFrame with >2 dimensions. If someone requests passing, running, and kicking data for 2014, 2018, and 2018, then return a single dataframe with 4 dimensions (year, table, player, stats).
6. `get_data` should automatically strip off the pro-bowl and all-pro data, and add separate columns for that.
7. Your _check_start_and_end_years method doesn't actually check. What happens if I request data for 1861?

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate your input. I have also been working on something that scrapes data from [The Football Database](https://www.footballdb.com/stats/index.html). A lot of the code is similar to the Pro Football Reference scraper, so would it make sense to have a `ProFootballReference` and `FootballDatabase` class that inherit from something like `AbstractNflScraper`? I'm more familiar with abstract classes in Java, where abstract methods don't contain implementation. I'm unsure what to do about potential repeated code because of this.

Comment: I think that's going to depend on how similar the two sites are. Does *The Football Database* produce similar stats? Does it make sense for both scrapers to have `get_passing_stats()` methods, for example? If so, then maybe there's a common base class. If not, if TFD provides different data completely, then you will end up "knowing" which one you are using, so sharing a common interface doesn't make sense.

Comment: I see what you're saying. No point in making something that gets data from two places if the data is same. Also, for something like `get_passing_stats()`, is it considered better to have both a `year` and `years` parameter? Why not just have a `years` parameter that can take both an `int` and `list`/`tuple` of `int`s?